# Python : TypeError when taking CSV data from url with IPython.display

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, ipython, data-science

I am trying to take the data from direct URL in python JupyterNotebook. but the error I am getting is really frustrating me .

Here is the Link which I am fetching:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data

I am simply using Jupyter Notebook function as:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data')
```

The error I am getting is the Following:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0a8be2c0a7c6> in <module>
      1 from IPython.display import HTML
----> 2 HTML('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\display.py in __init__(self, data, url, filename, metadata)
    693         if warn():
    694             warnings.warn("Consider using IPython.display.IFrame instead")
--> 695         super(HTML, self).__init__(data=data, url=url, filename=filename, metadata=metadata)
    696 
    697     def _repr_html_(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\display.py in __init__(self, data, url, filename, metadata)
    619 
    620         self.reload()
--> 621         self._check_data()
    622 
    623     def __repr__(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\display.py in _check_data(self)
    668     def _check_data(self):
    669         if self.data is not None and not isinstance(self.data, str):
--> 670             raise TypeError("%s expects text, not %r" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.data))
    671 
    672 class Pretty(TextDisplayObject):

TypeError: HTML expects text, not b'5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa\n4.6, ....
```

Any Help is really appreciated.

Comment: is the data in json format?

Comment: i think it's in csv format @SandrinJoy

Comment: yes the data is in csv format

Comment: please mention these in the question next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that [`HTML()`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.HTML) dosent expect CSV.

Use pandas [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to easily and conveniently read the CSV file:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data')
print(data)
```

Output:

```
     5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2     Iris-setosa
0    4.9  3.0  1.4  0.2     Iris-setosa
1    4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2     Iris-setosa
2    4.6  3.1  1.5  0.2     Iris-setosa
3    5.0  3.6  1.4  0.2     Iris-setosa
4    5.4  3.9  1.7  0.4     Iris-setosa
..   ...  ...  ...  ...             ...
144  6.7  3.0  5.2  2.3  Iris-virginica
145  6.3  2.5  5.0  1.9  Iris-virginica
146  6.5  3.0  5.2  2.0  Iris-virginica
147  6.2  3.4  5.4  2.3  Iris-virginica
148  5.9  3.0  5.1  1.8  Iris-virginica
```